# Create Trigger with condition and replace

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to create a trigger in MySQL with the help of which the value in the table column PRICE is set to 100 before each entry of a data record in the table ITEM, if a price is entered that is less than 100. I tried it out and it didnt work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `ITEM` 
FOR EACH ROW 
If ITEM.PRICE<100 
THEN 
UPDATE ITEM set PRICE=100; ENDIF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the values of the inserted record use the `new` pseudo record.

```
CREATE TRIGGER reggirt
               BEFORE INSERT
                      ON item
               FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF new.price < 100 THEN
    SET new.price = 100;
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON `item` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.price = GREATEST(NEW.price, 100);
```